# How do I add the title ("addmoves") to the server by angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

and I want to have and add a button for add one more movies. I want to send different data at the same time like:

```js
addmovies = [
  {
    movieName:"",
    diractor:"",
    releaseDate:""
  }, 
  {
    movieName:"",
    diractor:"",
    releaseDate:""
  }
];
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear..

Answer (score 0):

Look up [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in the Angular documentation. You will have to build up an object to pass via POST to your server-side controller. Once you have tried to write some code if you are still having problems try posting with a much more specific question and examples of what you have tried.